# Youtube app black and laggy transitions. S5 plus g901f

Tags: youtube, lagging

Maybe someone know where is the problem?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34Z5zNCSlyc
As you can see, video box is all black and transition is not smooth.
Even on my old s3 it's smooth as a butter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks perfectly fine to me. Not sure what you're seeing as a problem. The app works, plays videos and seems to transition just fine. In any case, try uninstalling the app and installing it again to see if that suits your needs. Good luck!